# Strange error when appending elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild

I've been getting a problem when trying to append an element in `JavaScript`, the error I've been getting looks a bit like this:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute `appendChild` on `Node`: parameter 1 is not of type `Node`.*

I'm also using using a `framework` called `Interact.js` just so you know

here's the peice of code that the browser isn't happy about:

```
var tempText = [];
var classNum = event.relatedTarget.getElementsByClassName('text');
var newCont = document.createElement('div');
for(var i = 0; i < classNum.length; i++){
    tempText.push(event.relatedTarget.getElementsByClassName('text')[i].textContent);
}
for(var i = 0; i < tempText.length; i++){
    var pText = document.createElement('p').appendChild(tempText);
    newCont.appendChild(pText[i]);

}

var placement = document.getElementById('toolbar')[0];
placement.appendChild(newCont);
```

Comment: Will you be able to use jQuery? Also, it is better you use the Stack Snippets to write the code along with HTML and CSS showing the whole thing as a demo.

Comment: yeah i can use Jquery

Comment: Great. I am answering it using jQuery.

Comment: I think you meant `appendChild(tempText[i])` and `appendChild(pText)` in the second  loop. Now you have it the other way around which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but I tried appending directly from the array and it returned a different error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed a small mistake. The `document.getElementById` returns only a single object. So don't use the `[0]`:

```
var placement = document.getElementById('toolbar'); // There is no [0]. Remove it.
placement.appendChild(newCont);
```

But the whole thing is really easy to do using jQuery. Since you are fine with using a jQuery solution, read on. Please include the jQuery library by adding this piece:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the JavaScript would be:

```js
var tempText = [];
var classNum = event.relatedTarget.getElementsByClassName('text');
var newCont = document.createElement('div');
for (var i = 0; i < classNum.length; i++) {
  tempText.push(event.relatedTarget.getElementsByClassName('text')[i].textContent);
}
for (var i = 0; i < tempText.length; i++) {
  // Change here:
  var pText = $("<p />", {html: tempText});
  $(newCont).append(pText);
}

var placement = $('#toolbar');
placement.append(newCont);
```

Since I am unaware of the HTML underlying, I just guessed it and converted a few to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question with `jquery`, you can condense your code to this:

```
var $newCont = $('<div>');
$('.text', event.relatedTarget).each(function() {
    $newCont.append($('<p>').append($(this).text())); 
})
$('#toolbar').append($newCont);
```

Or in a *functional programming* way:

```
$('#toolbar').append($('<div>').append(
    $('.text', event.relatedTarget).map(function() {
        return $('<p>').append($(this).text()); 
    }).get()
));
```

Comment: The OP is not using jQuery. I actually fixed the issue and gave a solution. `:)`

Comment: Great. I had based my answer on the OP's *"Yeah I can use jQuery"* and the presence of the `jquery` tag in the question.

Comment: Yes yes.. Just to let you know, I convinced the OP. Ha ha. `#BrainWashed`